# VSCODE - Breakpoints not being bounded

Tags: visual-studio-code

Currently I'm developing a cloud function using nestjs framework.

I'm able to run the application and receive the events from pub/sub. But my breakpoint are not bounded.

Here is my workspace file

```json
{
  "folders": [
    {
      "path": "."
    },
  ],
  "launch": {
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
      {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Attach",
        "sourceMaps": true,
        "skipFiles": [
          "<node_internals>/**"
        ],
        "outFiles": [
          "${workspaceFolder}/dist/**/*.js",
          "!**/node_modules/**"
        ],
        "console": "integratedTerminal",
        "preLaunchTask": "npm:debug",
        "postDebugTask": "stop:debug:tasks",
        "autoAttachChildProcesses": true,
      },
    ],
  },
   "tasks": {
     "version": "2.0.0",
     "tasks": [
            {
                "label": "npm:install",
                "type": "shell",
                "command": "npm install",
                "linux": {
                    "command": "if [ -d ${workspaceFolder}/node_modules ]; then npm install fi"
                },
                "windows": {
                    "command": "cmd",
                    "args": [
                        "/C",
                        "if not exist ${workspaceFolder}/node_modules  npm install"
                    ],
                },
                "options": {
                    "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
                },
            },
      {
        "label": "npm:start:dev",
        "type": "shell",
        "args": [
          "run",
          "start:dev",
        ],
        "command": "npm",
        "options": {
          "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        },
        "isBackground": true,
        "presentation": {
          "reveal": "always",
          "revealProblems": "onProblem",
          "close": true
         },
         "problemMatcher": [
           {
            "pattern":[
              {
                "regexp": ".",
                "file": 1,
                "location": 2,
                "message": 3
              }
            ],
             "background": {
               "activeOnStart": true,
               "beginsPattern": ".*Starting compilation in watch mode.*",
               "endsPattern": ".*Found [0-9] errors. Watching for file changes.*"
             }
           }
         ],
      },
       {
         "label": "npm:debug",
         "type": "shell",
         "args": [
           "run",
           "debug:function",
         ],
         "command": "npm",
         "options": {
           "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
         },
         "presentation": {
          "reveal": "always",
          "revealProblems": "onProblem",
          "close": true
         },
         "isBackground": true,
          "problemMatcher": [
            {
              "pattern":[
                {
                  "regexp": ".",
                  "file": 1,
                  "location": 2,
                  "message": 3
                }
              ],
              "background": {
                "activeOnStart": true,
                "beginsPattern": ".*Debugger listening.*",
                "endsPattern": ".*URL:*."
              }
            }
          ],
          "dependsOn": [
            "npm:start:dev"
          ]
       },
       {
        "label": "stop:debug:tasks",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "kill $(ps aux | grep '[n]ode --inspect' | awk '{print $2}')",
        "windows": {
          "command": "taskkill /F /IM node.exe"
        },
        "isBackground": true,
        "problemMatcher": [],
        "presentation": {
          "reveal": "always",
          "revealProblems": "onProblem",
          "close": true
         },
       }
     ]
   },
  "settings": {
    "debug.node.autoAttach": "on"
  },
  "extensions": {
    "recommendations": [
      "ms-dotnettools.dotnet-interactive-vscode"
    ]
  }
}
```

## tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictBindCallApply": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

## package.json

````json
{
  "name": "my-function",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "author": ":Vinicius Andrade",
  "private": true,
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "main": "dist/main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nest build",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\" \"test/**/*.ts\"",
    "start": "nest start",
    "start:dev": "nest start --watch",
    "start:debug": "nest start --debug --watch",
    "start:prod": "node dist/main",
    "lint": "eslint \"{src,apps,libs,test}/**/*.ts\" --fix",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "test:cov": "jest --coverage",
    "test:debug": "node --inspect-brk -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand",
    "test:e2e": "jest --config ./test/jest-e2e.json",
    "start:function": "functions-framework --source=dist/src/ --target=dataEnricher",
    "debug:function": "npx --node-options=--inspect @google-cloud/functions-framework --target=dataEnricher --signature-type=cloudevent --source=dist/main.js",
    "debug":"'npm run start:dev' & (sleep 5 && 'npm run debug:function')"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/functions-framework": "^3.3.0",
    "@google-cloud/logging-winston": "^5.3.0",
    "@google-cloud/pubsub": "^3.4.1",
    "@nestjs/common": "^9.0.0",
    "@nestjs/core": "^9.0.0",
    "@nestjs/microservices": "^9.3.12",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^9.0.0",
    "axios": "^1.3.5",
    "bull": "^4.10.4",
    "environment-override": "^1.0.3",
    "google-auth-library": "^8.7.0",
    "ip": "^1.1.8",
    "json5": "^2.2.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rxjs": "^7.2.0",
    "uuid": "^9.0.0",
    "winston": "^3.9.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nestjs/cli": "^9.0.0",
    "@nestjs/schematics": "^9.0.0",
    "@nestjs/testing": "^9.0.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/ip": "^1.1.0",
    "@types/node": "18.15.11",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.11",
    "@types/uuid": "^9.0.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.0.0",
    "concurrently": "^8.2.0",
    "eslint": "^8.0.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.22",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "prettier": "^2.3.2",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.20",
    "ts-loader": "^9.2.3",
    "ts-node": "^10.0.0",
    "tsconfig-paths": "4.2.0",
    "typescript": "^5.0.2"
  }
}


# main.js.map

```js
{"version":3,"file":"main.js","sourceRoot":"","sources":["../src/main.ts"],"names":[],"mappings":";;;AAGA,2EAA+D;AAC/D,wDAA4D;AAe5D,MAAM,eAAe,GAAG,IAAI,gCAAkB,EAAE,CAAC;AACjD,MAAM,QAAQ,GAAG,eAAe,CAAC,WAAW,EAAE,CAAC;AAC/C,MAAM,YAAY,GAAG,MAAA,QAAQ,aAAR,QAAQ,uBAAR,QAAQ,CAAE,MAAM,CAAC,YAAY,mCAAI,cAAc,CAAC;AACrE,IAAA,gCAAU,EAAC,YAAY,EAAE,KAAK,EAAE,KAAK,EAAE,EAAE;IACvC,OAAO,CAAC,GAAG,CAAC,QAAQ,CAAC,CAAC;IACtB,OAAO,CAAC,GAAG,CAAC,SAAS,CAAC,CAAC;AACzB,CAAC,CAAC,CAAC"}
````

I think it's releated to source maps, but I don't know what should I change.

I've tried to change the rootSource in tsconfig.json, but still the same.

[image]